# Трактовка чего-либо кем-либо?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Несмотря на кропотливую работу, которая предваряет всякий выход
>   актёра, даже в крошечной роли, я нередко ***сталкивалась с занятной
>   для меня трактовкой неподготовленного зрителя сценического действа***.

А если:

*...сталкивалась с занятной для меня трактовкой сценического действа неподготовленным зрителем.*

Comment: Это исправляет грамматику, но заложенная здесь логика с первого прочтения всё равно не осознаётся и требует додумывания, почему "несмотря на мою кропотливую работу их, неподготовленных зрителей, трактовка для меня занятна". Хоть и работаю, мне всё равно становится _любопытно_ - из-за них, неподготовленных. Может, "неожиданной" трактовкой (не той, на которую направлена работа)?

Comment: Неподготовленный зритель занятно для актёра трактовал его поведение на сцене.

Comment: Проведенное исправление необходимо, но все равно нагромождение слов (в основном существительных) без предлогов делает эту фразу тяжелой для восприятия.

Comment: А, переживём! )))